# Azimuth and Distance, NumericalDigitize, Numerical Vertex Edit, XY tools and other plugins are not on QGIS Plugin Manager version 2.0.1

Tags: qgis, plugins

Will these plugins no longer be available in QGIS 2.0.1?

Answer (score 7):

All plugins have to be rewritten to work with the new API.

If the authors did not do that yet, the plugins do not appear in the current plugin list. Some authors have added plugins and don't care about them anymore, or didn't get the message about the necessary update.

A kind request to the authors might help to get them back to the list.

Comment: ESRI has repeatedly, over many decades, made the same mistake: When you change your platform enough that all add-ins have to be rewritten, you ruin the good work of all users who contributed them. After you do that enough times (once is usually enough), smart users will learn that it is unproductive to write add-ins at all and you are left mainly with code contributed by unwitting neophytes. Do not underestimate the long-term value of a stable platform and reverse compatibility!

Comment: Well, ESRI has survived that mistake for decades, while QGIS is still quite young and growing fast ;-)

Comment: Yes, but you don't have the marketing juggernaut and docile installed user base needed to overcome those strategic errors. You only have the goodwill of a community that is extremely fragmented among a large number of open source and commercial offerings.  You lose that goodwill at your peril.

Comment: 'Mistake' and 'strategic error'? More like 'Catch-22.' In many instances, the plugin code can be reduced. Changes in the [PyQt4 handling of strings](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) and QVariants are very convenient to plugin writers, and were necessary to keep updated with changes in PyQt. The API for accessing features were significantly updated, allowing for much simpler access to feature attribute fields. These changes were not taken lightly by the QGIS developers; and, the 2.0 release was delayed since both API changes would prompt plugin code updates.

Comment: @whuber consider it a forced hand. We will be updating to Python 3 at some stage during the life of QGIS and PtQt4 would force switch to version 2 which would break even more plugins.  The API change was also needed for multithreading.  We decided to do it now when there isn't so many plugins in order to reduce that pain.  I very much doubt this kind of thing will happen again as there is no version 3 PyQt or anything that would require massive code changes.  See http://nathanw.net/2013/06/13/new-qgis-20-api/ for more details.

Comment: A is the wrong word for this.  Update is a better word.  In most cases you are removing extra PyQt logic that is no longer needed. Example `feature["column'"].toString()` just becomes `feature["column"]` because it's auto converted to `str/unicode`.  The change in how access features from a layer has changed but it's easy to see how it translates and is a easy (and better) fix.

Comment: @NathanW *et al.* Please understand I am not trying to sound critical of QGIS. I'm sure if backwards compatibility were easy to do, it would have been done. Having been burned badly once (by the ESRI ArcGIS 8 transition) and then having watched for a decade on the sidelines as user/developers got jerked around with practically every *minor* update to that software since then, I thought it might help to issue a cautionary note. Some long-term thinking on behalf of all your users and your developer community can pay off handsomely down the road.

Comment: I took the lead on that change and pushed the final commit to switch.  Trust me I spent about a week looking for a way to be backwards compatible.  In the end there was just no good and clean way to do it and I feel that would have hurt more then switching to a better API. 

The other thing to note here is **all** QGIS plugins are GPL.  The licence removes the higher risk of something just getting left to die because if you want/need it bad enough it can be fixed yourself or a by a dev and pushed back up  I have already done this with other peoples plugins when we changed the API.

Comment: Plugin "Numerical Digitize" and "Numerical Vertex Edit" are already running on qgis 2.0.
Thanks to the author for giving me the opportunity to work.