# QGIS Cloud in QGIS 2.0 missing and 2.0 Crashing

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

Is QGIS CLoud still missing off QGIS 2.0.

I am having a lot of issues with 2.0. on another matter I cannot load print templates without the system crashing. Are templates non compatible.

When i am also loading projects into 2.0 from 1.8 some raster layer properties have reset to default values....eg greyscale back to colour.

Comment: This is another "where are my QGIS plugins" question and a possible duplicate of [QGIS 2.0 Plugins missing](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72686/qgis-2-0-plugins-missing) and here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71841/azimuth-and-distance-numericaldigitize-numerical-vertex-edit-xy-tools-and-oth.  The templates issue is localised as it works for most other people (including me).  Raster rendering is done differently between the versions, hence the reversion to default settings.

Comment: It is best to create separate questions for each of your points. It is impossible for anyone to respond to your questions as asked.

Comment: I had assumed that QGIS Cloud was an integral part of QGIS and therefore an official pluggin and should have been carried over. Is there somewhere i can log to have issues and how do i go about it.

Comment: You could contact the plugin's developer or, if you have some programming ability, you could get the source code and up-date it yourself.  Check out the plugin's website.

Comment: QGIS Cloud is not a core plugin. It is a product of one of the companies who make their money with QGIS. They also offer a QGIS version with backwards compatible plugin API to their customers who have a lot of legacy plugins depending on the old API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just closing this as MappaGnosis suggest i am a bit over eager with my "where are my pluggins"

I still think there are A LOT of bugs in 2.0.